# ASP.NET Identity 2 Invalid no Two factor Provider Exists

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity-2, two-factor-authentication

For some reason EmailCode is not showing up in the valid two factor authentication providers. PhoneCode however did up until I removed it, now nothing shows up at all. I have debugged and it shows up under the UserManager, but for some odd reason GetValidTwoFactorProvidersAsync doesn't retrieve it. I've already attempted to manually add it by bypassing the method and retrieving the value manually, but then it throws the error message that the Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EmailTokenProvider does not exist. I am at a loss to explain why this isn't working.

```
        public async Task<ActionResult> SendCode(string returnUrl)
        {
            var userId = await SignInManager.GetVerifiedUserIdAsync();
            if (userId == null)
            {
                return View("Error");
            }
            var userFactors = await UserManager.GetValidTwoFactorProvidersAsync(userId);
            var factorOptions = userFactors.Select(purpose => new SelectListItem { Text = purpose, Value = purpose }).ToList();
            return View(new SendCodeViewModel { Providers = factorOptions, ReturnUrl = returnUrl });
        }
```

Identityconfig

```
            manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("EmailCode", new Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EmailTokenProvider<SystemUser>
                {
                    Subject = "SecurityCode",
                    BodyFormat = "Your security code is {0}"
                });

            manager.EmailService = new EmailService();
            var dataProtectionProvider = options.DataProtectionProvider;

            if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
            {
                manager.UserTokenProvider =
                    new DataProtectorTokenProvider<SystemUser>(
                        dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"));
            }
            return manager;
        }
```

Comment: how about just uninstalling AspNet.Identity and re-installing it using Nuget Package Manager or by any other means?

Comment: This is not possible without destroying a lot of work. Removing and reinstalling overwrites existing code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure you have a ConfirmedEmail for the User. You can look up the user in the database and look at the EmailConfirmed flag to see if it is set or not.

Comment: That was indeed the problem, I cannot believe how much time I wasted trying to figure out why it wasn't working. At least I know for the future to include an error message, and block access to two factor until the email is confirmed. Thanks!

Comment: what about a missing two factor phone number provider? what could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't see your codes and hence can't suggest a proper fix but I can tell you how I did it and all went okay. It came very handy and easy for me when I tried configuring  the application for 2 way authentication using these  links:

http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/features-api/two-factor-authentication-using-sms-and-email-with-aspnet-identity

http://typecastexception.com/post/2014/04/20/ASPNET-MVC-and-Identity-20-Understanding-the-Basics.aspx

Suggest you to try them if you haven't yet. Hope it helps!

Comment: Which parts do you need me to post. As I said above it is really strange that I can get the phone code to work, but not the email code (which is what I need). It is almost as though some bit of the code that validates the email two factor is damaged or removed. As I said, it shows up under the debugger as a two factor method, but fails to work when I set up the getvalidtwofactor method. The two tutorials above are coincidentally what I used originally to get the two factor working in the beginning, and offer no clues as to what could be causing this to fail.